# Is there a reverse for ArrayList.Adapter(IList)?

Tags: c#, generics, arraylist

According to MSDN, `ArrayList.Adapter(IList)` does the following:

> Adapter does not copy the contents of IList. Instead, it only creates
>   an ArrayList wrapper around IList; therefore, changes to the IList
>   also affect the ArrayList.

Is there a reverse operation that takes an `ArrayList` and returns a generic `IList<T>` wrapper?  i.e. A method that returns an `IList<T>` such that the source `ArrayList` also updates when the `IList<T>` changes?

e.g.

```
ArrayList foo = new ArrayList();

foo.Add(new Bar());
foo.Add(new Bar());

IList<Bar> foobar = foo.GenericAdapterMethod(); // insert the method I'm looking for here
foobar.Add(new Bar());

Console.WriteLine(foo.Count); // this should return 3
```

Comment: Were you aware that `ArrayList` shouldn't be used after .NET 1.1? If you need a list of arbitrary objects, use `List<object>`, otherwise use `List<T>` where `T` is the type of the object in the list, or use one of the other generic collections.

Comment: You should look into using generic classes instead of `ArrayList`. (Your question is tagged with "generics", but there is nothing in the question that uses generics.)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that generics are the way to go.  I intend to wrap a 1.1 library I don't have the source for in a 4.0 facade though.  So I'm afraid I don't have much of a choice.

Comment: @Guffa Oh yeah, edited the question to say what I really mean.  I need an IList<T> wrapper that actually proxies modifications back to the source ArrayList.

Comment: @Jeremy: There is no such wrapper in the framework, as that is inherently ineffective. If you can't find someone who have done that already, you have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since ArrayList implements IList, technically this also solves the reverse problem, since to this method you can pass an ArrayList and it returns a subclass of IList (unless of course you really care to get back a generic IList).

**Edit**: Since what you want is in fact IList, you can use inheritance to create a subclass of ArrayList and write the method that you need. The problem is that inside the subclass of ArrayList you still need to have a concrete class backing up the IList object that you are returning, otherwise there is no way to add objects to both lists.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a generic IList.  I'll edit the question to say this.  Sorry, it's past midnight here, I didn't think to get that in the first time around.